# How to create a iterable class

Tags: python-3.x, loops

Very simple. I have a class called Meeting(), and I need to know how to create a MeetingList() class that allows me to iterate through multiple Meeting() instances.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! Could you please describe in more detail which steps you have taken so far and where exactly the problem lies? Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Why do you need a `MeetingList` class though? Is it not the same as appending your `Meeting` objects into a list and iterate over it?

Comment: What I am developing accesses the REST api of BigBlueButton, an open source web conferencing system. I guess you're right. I am still learning python. If python allows objects to be used in say a dict, I could access them individually or iterate over them that way. What I want to do is:

1. Get meeting list from server (xml)
2. Dump that data into a data structure that can be iterated over, creating a meeting() for each meeting in the list.
3. Access each meeting individually. 

If I can throw objects into python lists, problem solved